# Bash source command not working with `curl`

Tags: bash, shell, url

I am trying to use `source` in-conjunction with `curl`.

However, when I run the following segment of code on my machine (Mac OS 10.13.4) it outputs the following error: `read_os_name: command not found`.

`read_os_name.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r UTILS_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicholasadamou/bash-utils/master/utils.sh"
source <(curl -s "$UTILS_URL")

read_os_name #Should output "macos"
```

`read_os_name()` from `utils.sh`:

```
read_os_name() {

    local kernelName=""

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    kernelName="$(uname -s)"

    if [ "$kernelName" == "Darwin" ]; then
        printf "macos"
    elif [ "$kernelName" == "Linux" ] && [ -e "/etc/os-release" ] || [ -e "/usr/lib/os-release" ]; then
        local conf=""

        if test -r /etc/os-release ; then 
            conf="/etc/os-release"
        else 
            conf="/usr/lib/os-release"
        fi

        awk -F= '$1=="ID" { print $2 ;}' "$conf" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
    fi

}
```

Comment: Is the command `read_os_name` inside the script?

Comment: @codeforester yes, `read_os_name` is inside the script being sourced.

Comment: The script works fine for me on RHEL.  Run your script as `bash -x ./read_os_name.sh` to see what is happening.

Comment: @codeforester it outputs the following: https://pastebin.com/raw/Lfsx5HQX and errors with: `read_os_name: command not found` probably because the `source` cmd isn't working for some reason. I agree, it works for me on Linux, but not on MacOS, which is my problem.

Comment: Run `curl -s "$UTILS_URL"` and see what it produces.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash` on your Mac?  `source` is a C-shell-ism imported into Bash — try using the original/native dot command (spelled `.`) instead of `source`.

Comment: As an aside, I think it is better to clone your git repo and use the scripts directly instead of the indirect method of using `curl` to get them.

Comment: @codeforester `curl -s "$UTILS_URL"` runs correctly by outputting the contents of the `utils.sh` on my git repo.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am certain I am using `bash` on my system. I have tried using the native dot command `. <file-name-here>` and the same problem occurs.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou And you're not running `sh yourscript`, right?

Comment: @codeforester the whole point of using this curl method is to allow me to type in 1 line of code into a `bash` file and gain access to the functions within it without actually having the file on my system.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, I am sure. I am running `bash read_os_name.sh`.